# Why calling list() on zip() empties the contents? How to print a zip object without changing the contents?

Tags: python

I just spent two hours chasing a bug down and realized it was due to this odd behavior. Why does iterating through a Python `zip` object also empties it? Sometimes I want to `print(list(zip))` for debug purposes while not changing the zip object. Is there a way to do that?

```
In [11]: a = zip([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])                                                                                                                                               

In [12]: print(list(a))                                                                                                                                 
[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]

In [13]: print(list(a))                                                                                                                                 
[]
```

Comment: No, you'd have to keep your list aroudn, i.e. `a = list(zip(a))`. This behavior isn't odd, btw, it is the same for all iterators, which `zip` objects are, but also `map` and `filter` objects, and generator objects... iterators are a pretty important part of python that you should get a handle on.

Comment: Because the `zip` object doesn't store any of the generated tuples. In fact, none of them are generated *until* you iterate over the `zip` object. This was the whole reason for changing `zip` from a function that returned a `list` (as it was in Python 2) into a class.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` creates an object for iterating once over the results. This also means it's exhausted after one iteration:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> z = zip(a,b)
>>> list(z)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> list(z)
[]
```

You need to call `zip(a,b)` every time you wish to use it or store the `list(zip(a,b))` result and use that repeatedly instead.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28390394/6505847)