# on calling a function which returns a dictionary more than once it returns empty dictionary. why is this happening and how can i fix it

Tags: python

I have created 2 scripts in python : script 2 contains 3 functions one to create a dictionary second to return a dictionary and third is a random function . and script 1 contains 5 functions
fun1 is to call create dictionary function fun2 , fun3 , fun4 are random calculation function and fun5 calls and print the return dictionary function.

Script 1:

```
from p2 import *

def fun1(keys,values):
    create_map(keys,values)

def fun2(n):
    rand_fun(n)

def fun3(n):
    rand_fun(n)


def fun4(n):
    rand_fun(n)


def fun5(lst):
    print(return_map(lst))

keys = [1,2,3]
values = ['a','b','c']
data = create_map(keys,values)
fun2(2)
fun3(3)
fun4(4)
dictionary = fun5(data)
dictionary1 = fun5(data)
dictionary2 = fun5(data)
```

Script 2:

```
def create_map(keys, values):
    return zip(keys,values)

def return_map(data):
    return dict(data)

def rand_fun(n):
    return print((n+1)%2)
```

The output is:

```
1
0
1
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
{}
{}
```

Why am i getting empty dictionary the second and third time and how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

reason:
`zip` can only use once.

reference:[Python zip object 'disappears' after iterating through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390354/python-zip-object-disappears-after-iterating-through)

code:

```
keys = [1,2,3]
values = ['a','b','c']
data = create_map(keys,values)
fun2(2)
fun3(3)
fun4(4)
dictionary = fun5(create_map(keys,values))
dictionary1 = fun5(create_map(keys,values))
dictionary2 = fun5(create_map(keys,values))
```

result:

```
1
0
1
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your create_map function to this.

```py
def create_map(keys, values):
    return dict(zip(keys,values))
```

like leaf_yakitori said zip can only be used once.